# set deledate in ItemsControl ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, xaml, delegates, itemscontrol, resourcedictionary

First, let me show you how my code is cut.

I have this code in a xaml UC (eventsUC.xaml) :

```
<UserControl x:Class="QuimeO.UserControls.Lists.EventsListUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ToggleSwitch="clr-namespace:ToggleSwitch;assembly=ToggleSwitch" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Width="477"
         >
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Width="auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" BorderThickness="0" x:Name="eventsList" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ItemsControl.Resources>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Name="eventslisttempplate" Source="EventsListTemplate.xaml"  />
            </ItemsControl.Resources>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>...
```

My EventsListTemplate.xaml looks like this :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    x:Class="QuimeO.UserControls.Lists.EventsListTemplate"
                    xmlns:apiNamespace="clr-namespace:QuimeO.DBO"
                    >
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type apiNamespace:EventsDictionary}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding FormatedDate}" FontSize="14"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <ListView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="eventsList" ItemsSource="{Binding Events}" BorderThickness="0" MouseDoubleClick="eventsList_MouseDoubleClick">
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And my EventsListTemplate.xaml.cs code behind looks like this

```
public partial class EventsListTemplate : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public Delegate MainWindowControlPointer;

        private void eventsList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var ev = ((sender as ListView).SelectedItem as ListViewItem).DataContext as Event;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ev.Name);

            this.MainWindowControlPointer.DynamicInvoke(ev.Ancestors.Root, new Element() { Category = ev.Category, Id = ev.Id, Name = ev.Name });
        }
    }
```

When I click on an item of my listview in my template, it trigger the eventsList_MouseDoubleCkick and I can retrieve my event.

However, I would like to trigger an action in the UC where the template is created (first source code block).

To do that, I just want to create a delegate in my Template (technicaly, in a perfect world, something like "this.rd_eventslisttemplate.MainWindowControlPointer = ... "). But, I don't know how to do it or if this is even possible.

Comment: You have a template. Inside your template you have a Button. When you click on your Button you to call a method which is inside the control which uses your template. Basically you wish to call a method which is in ItemsControl. Did I get you right?

Comment: When I click on the button, now, it calls a method which is inside the template. What I would like to do is to call a method which is actually inside the control which uses the template.

Comment: The control which uses the template is ItemsControl right? So what is the name of the method you wish to call?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't understand what you said. I have updated my post with more code. My ItemsControl is in a UserControl (EventsListUC). It is in this usercontrol that I would like to catch the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After encrypting your question for a while I think I got it.

There is a nice method called VisualTreeHelper.GetParent() which gets you the parent of a control in VisualTree.

Now to your problem when you catch your event in EventsListTemplate you will need to call GetParent() few times till you finally get the instance of your UserControl.

Thats it.

Comment: I tried to use "var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);" but it have a compilation error : "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(System.Windows.DependencyObject)' has some invalid arguments", "cannot convert from 'QuimeO.UserControls.Lists.EventsListTemplate' to 'System.Windows.DependencyObject'"

Comment: Ok, got it : VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as DependencyObject); works. Thanks, I will now try to get my UserControl :)

Comment: Yea, you got it. Only DependencyObjects are allowed.